# Cannot find protocol declaration ios7

Tags: ios

I've declared a protocol named `ScrollableTimelineViewProtocol` in a file `ScrollableTimelineView.h`  as below :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AbstractView.h"
#import "RedTimeIndicator.h"
#import "EventsModel.h"
#import "TimeStrands.h"
#define LABEL_TAG_OFFSET -500

@protocol ScrollableTimelineViewProtocol <NSObject>
- (void) showPopup : (NSInteger)tag;

@end



@interface ScrollableTimelineView : UIView<TimeStrandDelegate,UIScrollViewDelegate>
{
}
@property (nonatomic,assign) id<ScrollableTimelineViewProtocol> delegate;
```

And I'm trying to use it in a view controller :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AbstractViewController.h"
#import "TimeStrands.h"
#import "ScrollableTimelineView.h"


@protocol TimelineDelegate <NSObject>
- (void) detailedShownDelegate;
- (void) detailedViewHiddenDelegate;

@end

@interface TimelineViewController : UIViewController<ScrollableTimelineViewProtocol>;
```

But I get an error saying `Could not find protocol declartion for ScrollableTimelineViewProtocol`. Help.

Comment: semi colon will not come at the end of this statement      '@interface TimelineViewController : UIViewController<ScrollableTimelineViewProtocol>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There should not be semicolon at the end
2. Import the class where ScrollableTimelineViewProtocol declared.

Answer (score 1):

```
@protocol scrollableTimelineViewProtocol;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tblView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet id<scrollableTimelineViewProtocol> delegate;

@end
@protocol scrollableTimelineViewProtocol <NSObject>

-(void)runFast;

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simple... Try this...

Remove semocolon from **interface**..

```
@interface TimelineViewController : UIViewController<ScrollableTimelineViewProtocol>;
```

Into

```
@interface TimelineViewController : UIViewController<ScrollableTimelineViewProtocol>
```